# How to add User Inputs to PDF document

Tags: pdf, firebase-realtime-database, itext, pdf-generation, jspdf

So I am quite new to React Native but I understand its functionality as an app that works on both Android and IOS devices. Simply put, I am working on an app that generates a PDF document (usually a legal document) using User Inputs.

SO far, I have created the app such that all the user inputs are stored at different nodes of my Firebase JSON tree in the firebase Database.

However, I am not quite sure How to generate a PDF document with these user inputs. For example, I expect the user to fill out a form with information:

```
Full name: John Doe

Address: 1234 Stackoverflow Drive 

Date: 22/01/2021
```

I aim for a PDF document to be generated as follows:

Hi there! My name is `John Doe` and my address is `1234 Stackoverflow Drive`. The date of this Agreement is `22/01/2021`

I would not mind going the cloud function route or doing the heavy lifting directly in the app but I wondered if there were ways in which PDF documents could be generated using these user inputs from the firebase database.

Comment: You already added tags for iText and jspdf. Where is your code? What did you try?

Comment: Judging from your description of your requirements I think [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) seems to be a good fit.